# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000011007db07, pid=28353, tid=259

Tags: java, javafx, fatal-error, jvm-crash

I have the following error when running a project and I am unsure how to solve it:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010e109b07, pid=43754, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu18.28+13-CA (18.0+37) (build 18+37)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu18.28+13-CA (18+37, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x583b07]  jni_NewLocalRef+0x37
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://www.azul.com/support/
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53987:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MainMenu.PirateMenu

Host: "MacBookPro15,4" x86_64 1400 MHz, 8 cores, 8G, Darwin 21.4.0, macOS 10.16 (21E258)
Time: Mon Apr 11 21:19:22 2022 EDT elapsed time: 10.077687 seconds (0d 0h 0m 10s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

Stack: [0x00007ff7b2dda000,0x00007ff7b35da000],  sp=0x00007ff7b35d5e60,  free space=8175k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x583b07]  jni_NewLocalRef+0x37
C  [libawt_lwawt.dylib+0x29ed0]  -[CGLLayer drawInCGLContext:pixelFormat:forLayerTime:displayTime:]+0x2b0
C  [QuartzCore+0xc121e]  _ZL17CAOpenGLLayerDrawP13CAOpenGLLayerdPK11CVTimeStampj+0x7dd
C  [QuartzCore+0xc0863]  -[CAOpenGLLayer _display]+0x249
C  [QuartzCore+0x20951]  _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE+0x369
C  [QuartzCore+0x177336]  _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd+0x280
C  [QuartzCore+0x2231]  _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv+0x309
C  [QuartzCore+0x1ac6d6]  _ZN2CA11Transaction25flush_as_runloop_observerEb+0x80
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7ee90]  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__+0x17
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7ed22]  __CFRunLoopDoObservers+0x21f
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7e2d7]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x46b
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7d7ac]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x232
C  [libjli.dylib+0x6be2]  CreateExecutionEnvironment+0x192
C  [libjli.dylib+0x26b7]  JLI_Launch+0x607
C  [java+0xc0e]  main+0x19e
C  0x000000011bf8a51e


siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000330
```

The problem occurs when I click the start button in the main menu. A user customization window should be opened, but instead the program crashes. The code, which includes Java and JavaFX, is in this zip file:
https://app.box.com/s/3b5i78ntp8e7wu0zdl1vqoace30h2vuo

Here is the java problem report:
https://app.box.com/s/pn5cz1ac5hnu0twu89dunxo6kznrfspa

My terminal says I have four JDKs and my current version is zulu 18:

```
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ chriswodkiewicz$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    18 (x86_64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 18.28.13" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home
    16.0.2 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 16" /Users/chriswodkiewicz/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-16.0.2/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_322 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Users/chriswodkiewicz/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_322/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_311 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ chriswodkiewicz$ java -version
openjdk version "18" 2022-03-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu18.28+13-CA (build 18+37)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu18.28+13-CA (build 18+37, mixed mode, sharing)
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ chriswodkiewicz$
```

My friend runs the same exact program successfully with Netbeans 12 and JDK 8 on windows. Unfortunately, I have the same issue even when using this version. On IntelliJ and VScode the problem persists. If anyone knows the solution to this problem it would be greatly appreciated. I am a novice and I want to know the reason behind this so I don't have similar issues in the future.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] which reproduces the issue and put the code in your question rather than an offsite link?  Similarly for the "java problem report'.  (I didn't click on your links, so I don't know what is in them).  Also, please include step-by-step reproduction instructions, so that anybody could follow them and get your error.

Comment: I suggest you remove the unused (outdated) JDKs (they are probably not your issue, but it simplifies your environment).

Comment: Does a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) work in your environment? or do you get the same crash?  Also, what kind of Mac is it?  M1 or Intel?

Comment: Yes I can create and run a JavaFX project. I actually tested other JavaFX games that worked on VScode as well. My Macbook's processor is 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5. I will try to delete old JDKs to see if it works. As for the links, I did not have enough characters to fit everything so this is what I had to resort to unfortunately.

Comment: You can edit the question to add more information. Unlike comments, questions aren't limited in the number of characters you can write.  You don't need to (and should not) provide your full project code, only the minimum specific executable code that is required to replicate the issue (and yes that may require you do some work to find out what that code is and produce the minimal example).

Comment: I added more from the log which included the problematic frame. I think the issue in the code that I realized may be the com.sun import. Does a different JDK fix this?

Comment: You should not import com.sun. If you want debug help please follow the requests in the prior comments.

Comment: Usually a crash like this means an improperly configured app where you have placed native libraries on your path that do not match the Java binaries on your path.  Or incorrect threading and race conditions. Whether that is your problem, I could not say.